# Consulta com pause?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, bootstrap

bem estou fazendo um menu dinamico php onde gostaria nao usar consulta dentro de outra, atualmente estou buscando da tabela CATEGORIA  o nome da categoria e dentro dela estou buscando em outra tabela PAGINAS os resultados que tiver no campo de categorias o mesmo que ha na tabela CATEGORIA. Existe algo que encurte esse codigo ? ou maneira de consulta diretamente na tabela que possa dar o mesmo resultado?

Exemplo do menu:

```
   // primeira consulta pego da tabela categoria todos os tipos de categorias que existe
   $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM categorias");
   //faco o loop
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { 
   // defino a categoria 
   $categoria = $row['titulo'];?>
    // imprimo o nome do menu
   <li> <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
         <?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></a>
    /// abro a categoria sub menu
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">

    // faco a segunda consulta
    <? $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE categoria = '$categoria' ");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
    <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></a></li>
    // fecho as 2 consultas
    <?php }} ?>
```

Ah sim quanto ao titulo CONSULTA COM PAUSE, era algo que pensei que poderia dar certo tipo a cada resultado da 1ª consulta  executar a segunda automaticamente, a logica parece simples mais a execução ta complicada.

Comment: Use um [JOIN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118352).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem duas formas, uma é com query preparada, entendo que é mais perto do que você quiz descrever com "CONSULTA COM PAUSE", e a outra é usar um left join para selecionar todos os registros de ambas as tabelas, selecionando linhas da esquerda mesmo que não existam linhas associadas na da direita.

Query preparada

```
<?php
// prepara a query de páginas
$stmtPaginas = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE categoria = ? ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtPaginas, "s", $categoria);

// lê as categorias
$results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM categorias");
// faz o loop
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { 
  // Coloca valor na variável categoria, que é a chave da tabela paginas
  $categoria = $row['titulo'];
  // abre o menu
  ?><li> <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
  <?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></a>
  <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
  <?php
  // executa a query preparada
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtPaginas);
  $resultPaginas = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmtPaginas);
  while ($rowPaginas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultPaginas)) {
    ?>
  <li><a href="#"><?php echo $rowPaginas['titulo']; ?></a></li>
  <?php 
  }
  ?>
  </ul></li>
  <?php
}
// fecha a query preparada
mysqli_stmt_close($resultPaginas);
?>
```

Left Join

```
<?php
// primeira consulta pego da tabela categoria todos os tipos de categorias que existe
$results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT categorias.*, paginas.* FROM categorias LEFT JOIN paginas ON paginas.categoria = categorias.titulo");
// Define algumas variáveis de controle
$ultima_categoria = null;
//faz o loop
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { 
  // se é uma nova categoria, imprime o li de categoria, e se não for a primeira, fecha o ul e li anterior
  if ($ultima_categoria != $row['categorias.titulo']){
    if (!is_null($ultima_categoria)) {
      ?></ul></li><?php
    }
    ?><li><a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <?php echo $row['categorias.titulo']; ?></a><ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu"><?php
    $ultima_categoria = $row['categorias.titulo'];
  }
  // Se existir página nessa linha, imprime
  if (!is_null($row['paginas.titulo'])) {
    ?><li><a href="#"><?php echo $row['paginas.titulo']; ?></a></li><?php
  } 
}
// a última categoria fica aberta, entao testa se houve categoria, se houve, fecha aqui
if (!is_null($ultima_categoria)) {
  ?></ul></li><?php
}
?>
```

Não testei nenhum dos dois exemplos, o primeiro deve funcionar, talvez precise uns pequenos ajustes, o segundo não sei a parte que chama as colunas com o nome da tabela, não lembro se o mysqli aceita assim, o melhor seria especificar todas as colunas e colocar alias único para cada uma, aí certeza que funciona.

Você deveria usar chaves numéricas para fazer relacionamentos entre tabelas, é mais eficiente para o banco de dados que usar um texto.

Comment: boa vc entendeu bem o que tentei passar , vou testar e estudar isso que me passou. De todo modo essa segunda opção faz somente uma consulta ao bd acho que deve impactar mais na performace.( nao sei ao certo se menos consultas = melhor desempenho mais parto dessa logica)

Comment: Normalmente menos consultas é melhor sim, principalmente em relação a queries recursivas que se repetem. Na primeira opção que passei a segunda query é executada várias vezes mas ela é preparada, é como se o banco de dados compilasse o que ele vai rodar e depois usa já no formato compilado, fica mais eficiente. De qualquer modo ainda acho que a segunda opção é mais eficiente que a primeira. Outras coisas a fazer, como eu já citei é fazer o tipo que relaciona as tabelas ser número inteiro e especificar somente as colunas necessárias, e ainda pode usar alias que eu estou mais certo que funciona.